# GitHub dependabot not setting reviewers at all

Tags: github, dependabot

I'm trying to make PRs opened by Dependabot to set some reviewers, but it seems that it doesn't work for either a team or a specific user.

My **dependabot.yml** file:

```
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "pip"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
    reviewers:
    #  - "org/cloud-approvers"
      - "user1"
      - "user2"
      - "user3"
```

I have made sure that the identities are correct, meaning if I type `@cloud-approvers` I see the autocomplete shows me `org-name/cloud-approvers`.
The same goes for the dedicated users, if I type `@user1` I see the autocomplete and copy the exact same name.
The reason for the team being commented out, is since I saw it wasn't working - so I wrote the team members implicitly instead - but this also seems not working.

Any advise please?
Thanks,
Lior

Comment: Bumping the thread

Comment: Bumping the thread again

Comment: Bumping the thread once again

Comment: Bumping the thread yet again

Comment: Bumping the thread hoping for someone to help

Comment: Bumping the thread hoping for someone to help

Comment: Bumping the thread hoping for someone to help